# PowerShell - Backslash at end when using variables

Tags: powershell, backslash, robocopy

I´ve a small problem i didnt understand...
i want to fire-up robocopy with source/target information from a variable.

```
$source = $TDU2Backup_Path+$dir_array[$i]+$file_array[$i]
$target = $TDU2Unpacked_Path+$dir_array[$i]+$file_array[$i]
```

when i print the var. content with write-host everything is fine, i get something like that:

```
D:\spiele\TDU2Community\Euro\Bnk\islands\ibiza\level\area-1\area-1-3\sector-1-3-4-2.bnk
D:\spiele\TDU2Community\Backup\gas-station-xandernl\Euro\Bnk\islands\ibiza\level\area-1\area-1-3\sector-1-3-4-2.bnk
```

but, if i use the var. with robocopy (or xcopy or something like that), i have always a backslash at the end

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Quelle : D:\spiele\TDU2Community\Euro\Bnk\islands\ibiza\level\area-1\area-1-3\sector-1-3-4-2.bnk\

Ziel : D:\spiele\TDU2Community\Backup\gas-station-by-xandernl\Euro\Bnk\islands\ibiza\level\area-1\area-1-3\sector-1-3-4-2.bnk\

Dateien : * . *

Optionen: * . * /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Variable Output as string and using in robocopy not the same]

Comment: I would use [Join-Path](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849799.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Instead of manually building the path then you can verify using [Resolve-Path](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849858.aspx).

Comment: `robocopy` expect source and destination to be directories not files. You should write your command like this: `robocopy D:\spiele\TDU2Community\Euro\Bnk\islands\ibiza\level\area-1\area-1-3 D:\spiele\TDU2Community\Backup\gas-station-xandernl\Euro\Bnk\islands\ibiza\level\area-1\area-1-3 sector-1-3-4-2.bnk`.

Comment: thank you,too for explain robocopy info. now i understand what happend.

@jkdba: thank you so much...this is a better practice. Works fine!